# Calculate this determinant by induction I think?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant

$$
    D_{n+1}=\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x_1 & x_1^2 &...&x_1^n \\
    1 & x_2 & x_2^2 &...&x_2^n \\
      & ... &       &...     \\
    1 & x_n & x_n^2 &...&x_n^n \\
    2 & 2   & 2     &...   &2\\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

I am trying to use the reduction method and I hope get a recurrence formula by comparing $D_{n+1}$ and $D_{n}$. So, in order to kill the $x_{n}$ part, I expand the row $n$ as
$
    D_{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 &...&x_1^n \\
    x_2 & x_2^2 & x_2^3 &...&x_2^n \\
      & ... &       &...     \\
    x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & x_{n-1}^3 &...&x_{n-1}^n \\
    2 & 2   & 2     &...   &2\\
    \end{vmatrix}
$
+
$
    (-1)^{n+2}x_{n}\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 &...&x_1^n \\
    1 & x_2^2 & x_2^3 &...&x_2^n \\
      & ... &       &...     \\
    1 & x_{n-1}^2 & x_{n-1}^3 &...&x_{n-1}^n \\
    2 & 2   & 2     &...   &2\\
    \end{vmatrix}
$
+
$...$
+
$
    (-1)^{2n+1}x_{n}^n\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & x_1 & x_1^2 &...&x_1^{n-1} \\
    1 & x_2 & x_2^2 &...&x_2^{n-1} \\
      & ... &       &...     \\
    1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 &...&x_{n-1}^{n-1} \\
    2 & 2   & 2     &...   &2\\
    \end{vmatrix}
$

but I can't find the relationship with $D_{n}.$ Can someone give some hints? Great thanks!

Comment: Hint: replace the last row with $2, 2a, 2a^2, \dots, 2a^n$.

Comment: @dxiv This becomes the direct application of Vander Monde determinant by taking $x_{n+1}=1$....Great thanks.

Comment: Right, that's the idea (except it's Vandermonde in one word). If you work out the details and post a self-answer I'll +1 it.